# Get list of currently dispatched events

Tags: magento

I know this question may seem weird but I'd like to get a list of currently dispatched events.
The thing is that I am a lazy man and I would like to check if the 'checkout_cart_add_product_complete' has been fired without creating an observer for it.

So the idea is to get an array of all dispatched events and do an in_array on it :)

I thought that Mage::getEvents()->getAllEvents() would throw some info but it just returns an empty array.

I also digged a bit in lib/Varien/Event files and folders but didn't manage to be successful at creating an observer programmatically. Yep, I know, why being simple while one can be complicated ? :)

So this main question (getting a list of dispatched events) hides another (for the pure knowledge) wich would be "how to create an observer programmatically".

What do you think?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `dispatchEvent` and you'll see that events are only loaded from the assorted config.xml files, via SimpleXML. I cannot see any way to intercept this except to override `Mage_Core_Model_App`.

Of course there cannot be an event-dispatched-event, that would create an infinite loop, so there is no way to observe all events.

If you need to see events for development my advice would be to set a breakpoint in `dispatchEvent` with your debugger, that way you get to see not only the event names but also the objects passed as parameters too. I've tried [other ways before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5279938/471559) but this was most convenient for me.

Comment: Yep... that's the conclusion I am compelled to accept as indeed, obsevers are loaded within the config so there is no way to create one afterwards if I'm correct. I tried to do a Mage::addObserver() with all correct arguments and I got no error but no output either. I must then create a small module just to oberve one event... Not very elegant but it seems this is the Magento way :) Thanks!

Comment: `Mage::addObserver` is vestigial. It looks like the mage event model got replaced with an app event model so it no longer has an effect.

Answer (score 0):

I need to do the same and I think it's possible to trick magento by the function getEventConfig in Mage_Core_Model_Config. You could force him to add automatically a default observer.

Comment: Apparently it's not possible to rewrite the class Mage_Core_Model_Config, so my idea can't work.