# Magento which event is called? Need to build an observer

Tags: events, magento, observer-pattern, mage

I need to create an observer in Magento that listens for the event that is called when someone re-indexes the Catalog Search Index.

So which event is called when someone indexes Catalog Search Index?  Thanks?

Edit: 
I am looking at the event:
catalogindex_plain_reindex_after

Would this be the correct one?

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend running this grep from command line and building out an events txt file of available events you can hook into.  That list may be pretty dated you linked.

`grep -r Mage::dispatchEvent /path/to/your/Magento/* > events.txt`

Comment: Also, there are some lists available online, like `http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/events` for quick reference :-)

Comment: I have never connected through SSH to our server and I tried for the first time and the grep command said I could not access my domain.  Is there an event that we are sure is in every Magento installation such as...controller_front_init_routers so I could test to see if my observer is even working?

Comment: I noticed my command line was invalid with the *.php i've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you need an observer on a certain page, you can uncomment the Varien_Profiler in index.php and enable it in the Developer section of the config. Once it is enabled you should see a table on the bottom of your page with everything that happened on that page. Look for `DISPATCH EVENT:`.

Comment: Useful. And could have made an excellent answer to a [year old question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5279938/471559) of mine.