# Is there a comprehensive list of observer events?

Tags: magento

Is there a comprehensive list of all events that can be listened for?

If this list doesn't exist, what's the best method to debug to obtain all events?

Comment: If you search for Mage::dispatchEvent on entire project you'll found all events.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll never find a complete list.  But if you go to app/Mage.php you can put in some debug code inside of the function "dispatchEvent()" and log all of the events as you go.

```
$params = array();
foreach (array_keys($data) as $key) {
    if (is_object($data[$key])) {
        $params[] = $key.' ('.get_class($data[$key]).')';
    } else {
        $params[] = $key.' ('.gettype($data[$key]).')';
    }
}
Mage::log('event_name:'.$name.',event_passed_keys:'.implode('|',$params),null,'events.log',true);
```

Then using some excel wizardry you can parse those out into a list of all of the event names and parameters being passed to it.

The problem with many of the compiled lists or even doing the grep as shown above is that many of the events are dynamically created.  Which lets you discern what events there are that aren't listed.

Make sure to comment out that debug code or the events.log file will become huge after just a short time.

Comment: It's the dynamic events that prompted this question. I know there are several valid events that aren't included in any of the comprehensive lists.

Comment: Yep!  Which is solved by this code. I don't know how many events that I've discovered I could use by logging all of the ones that were fired.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at a list of events @

- http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/
- [Customize Magento using Event/Observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

or

To log all the event for a specific page in your dev environment you could add `Mage::log($eventName);`

in  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php

```
public function dispatchEvent($eventName, $args){
    Mage::log($eventName); 
    ....
```

or

```
grep -r Mage::dispatchEvent /path/to/your/Magento/* > events.txt
```

Read more @

- [Magento which event is called? Need to build an observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016027/magento-which-event-is-called-need-to-build-an-observer)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153/where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-magento-events

Answer (score 1):

As an exercise I wrote a Bash script to generate rough list of events (it actually acts as a wrapper to grep with a few switches to provide context and available params).

I've used this script to generate events lists for default Magento installations for versions 1.3.3.0 to 1.8.0.0 version and the code is available at GitHub:

https://github.com/Marko-M/magento-events-list/

Lists of events are available here:

https://github.com/Marko-M/magento-events-list/tree/master/magento-outofthebox

and a follow up article on my blog here:

http://www.techytalk.info/bash-script-to-generate-list-of-events-for-magento-installation/

Be aware that these lists can never be complete due to many event names being generated dynamically.

As you probably have extensions on your project and they dispatch their own events, it's even better to generate this list manually trough grep or using my script.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

a general mean is to set an observer for any specific event you are interesting in

see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/314/how-to-know-the-magento-event-that-we-want-to-hook

in the module Logevent, the config.xml

0.1

Maticode_Logevent_Model

```
<controller_action_predispatch>
    <observers>
        <Logevent>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Logevent/observer</class>
            <method>controller_action_predispatch</method>
        </Logevent>
    </observers>
</controller_action_predispatch>
```

and the Model/observer.php

```
    <?php
```

class Maticode_Logevent_Model_Observer {
 public function controller_action_predispatch($observer) {
Mage::log ( $observer->getEvent ()->getControllerAction ()->getFullActionName (),null, 'eventlog.log' );
}

}

This way , in the

```
var/log/eventlog.log file
```

u can visualize a possible hook on any tested actions (click on a button and check your log )