# Magento event name to observe

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I need to add some code to Magento (1.6.2) to be executed when an orders status becomes Complete.
In our system, this happens when the order is "Shipped" - i.e. the "Ship" button is clicked, and the shipping info is saved.

I have hunted (obviously in the wrong places) to try and find what that event would be called, so that I can add an observer to watch for it firing, and then run my code.

Can anyone tell me what the name of this event would be (if it exists as an observable event) please?

Cheers!

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but it may help. We use the following script to find all the events that Magento can dispatch: `grep --color=never -hoR "Mage::dispatchEvent('[^']*'" . | sed -e "s/Mage::dispatchEvent(//" -e "s/'//g" | sort -u` (One warning: Some of these events never actually dispatch.)

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237400/is-there-a-comprehensive-list-of-observer-events

Comment: Thanks for the code there. I now have a list of events, but I don't see any that fit my requirement. I take it this means one doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too find [event hunting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5279938/471559) to be a bit of a dark art.  In this case I would try `sales_order_save_before` and then check in a handler like this:

```
function onSalesOrderSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    if (($order->getData('status') == 'complete')
     && ($order->getOrigData('status') != 'complete')) {
        // then order has just been completed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create a custom module that override this controller

> /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/ShipmentController.php

Then add your custom code or create you own custom event in `public function saveAction()`